# Image with transparent overlay for sound playback progress bar

Tags: android, overlay, customization, progress, seekbar

I have an app that records, stores, and plays back ~30 second sound clips recorded by users. It also records the location that the sound was tagged at. During playback, however, instead of a SeekBar, I would like to create a custom progress bar over a static Google maps image of the sound's location, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65HOO.png).

Pressing the map once would begin playback, and pressing it again would pause playback.

I know how to get the maps image and code for starting/pausing playback, but now I would like to add the progress overlay to it. Any suggestions or guidance on how to achieve this? I saw a few questions around styling the background color of a traditional SeekBar, but I don't think that's enough for me to achieve the above look. Thank you!

PS - Any code examples/samples would also be MUCH appreciated! First time Android programmer here.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to implement your task, I would use a `FrameLayout` (specified in my layout XML file with no children) and then I would programmatically add the `Views` that I need to it. The first `View` added to the `FrameLayout` is always at the bottom and the last one stays at the top. I would use `LayoutParams` to determine the position of each `View` in the `FrameLayout`.

Sample Layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Initialize the `FrameLayout` in the activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

    // set the imageview's layout parameters relative to the frame layout's parameters
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(frameLayout.getWidth(), frameLayout.getHeight());

    imageViewParams.gravity = Gravity.FILL;
    imageViewParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    imageViewParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    // create the map image view
    ImageView mapImageView = new ImageView(this);

    mapImageView.setImageBitmap(mapBitmap);
    mapImageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);

    // set the progressbar's layout parameters relative to the frame layout's parameters
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams progressBarHorizontalParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(frameLayout.getWidth(), frameLayout.getHeight());

    progressBarHorizontalParams.gravity = Gravity.FILL;
    progressBarHorizontalParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    progressBarHorizontalParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    // create the progress bar 
    ProgressBar progressBarHorizontal = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    progressBarHorizontal.setLayoutParams(progressBarHorizontalParams);
    // make the progress bar transparent
    progressBarHorizontal.setAlpha(0.3f);

    // add the view(s) to the frame layout
    frameLayout.addView(mapImageView);
    frameLayout.addView(progressBarHorizontal);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, iRuth, and for adding the helpful code in! I see how your way would turn the map image into a frame layout to overlay. One more question - how would I then get the sound playback progress "bar" to overlay on it?

Comment: Add it to the `FrameLayout` after you've added the `mapImageView`. As I mentioned in my answer, the last view that is added to the `FrameLayout` is at the top.

Comment: But that's the part I'm unsure of - how to isolate the progress part of the seekbar and format it be a wide, transparent overlay.

Comment: Hi @iRuth, do you think this would still work if I replaced the image view of the map with an image button? I need the map to also serve as the play/stop button.

Comment: You could add an `onClickListener` to the image view instead.